# Error page in Tomcat is replaced by other error pages

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have setup in my web.xml the following:

```
<error-page>
 <error-code>404</error-code>
 <location>/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

This is working fine, I get the error pages i'm expecting. However, in some places in the application code they have defined their own status template which is shown in these specific URLs/APIs

The biggest issue I have with these custom templates is that they are showing stack traces and application versions, which obviously is a security risk.

So my question really is if it's possible to have tomcat override all error pages and show a generic one?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an someOtherError.jsp page.
in the web.xml create as your catch-all

```
`<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/403.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
  <location>/someOtherError.jsp</location>
</error-page>`
```

add then include code to handle the specific errors.

```
`<body>
    <% if(response.getStatus() == 500){ %>
        <font color="red">Error: <%=exception.getMessage() %></font><br>
        <%@ include file="login.jsp"%>
    <%}else {%>
        Error code is <%=response.getStatus() %><br>
        Blah blah blah...
    <%} %>
</body>`
```

Comment: I don't think you fully understand my question. The issue I have is that some APIs in the application has defined their own status template (let's say 404). So whenever I got to localhost/notarealpage I get my generic error404.jsp page. But when I go to localhost/api/service/notarealpage I get another "specific" 404 page that from the specific status template. What I want is that the tomcat page should also override this status page.

Comment: Since your tomcat xml.web is the configuration for your application I don't understand why you can't configure these outputs. It is very hard to visualize what you are talking about. Can you include an example. What API? provide a minimally working example.

Comment: It seems as there are several layers of "error" pages in play for this specific use case. I've noticed that you can setup error pages on the following layers nginx > tomcat > application(s). It seems as the "most specific" error page takes precedence of which error page that should be shown. What I did to solve my issue is trying to find all these error pages and override them with my own custom one.